# Further explanation of the Penrose Conjecture

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass, differential-geometry, event-horizon

I'm currently a third year maths undergrad, writing a dissertation on the application of minimal surfaces in space.

I have recently come across the [Penrose Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_Penrose_inequality) that the mass of a spacetime is:

$$ m \geq \sqrt{\dfrac{A}{16 \pi}}.$$

What significance does this have in terms of the geometry of a black hole? Also how does this directly relate to that of minimal surfaces? In that, is it purely to do with the apparent horizons corresponding to a minimal surface?

Comment: See arXiv:math/9911173 [math.DG]. Though I have not managed to find time to begin reading the paper, the abstract's second paragraph talks quite a lot about Schwarzschild black holes.

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: A Schwarschild black hole of mass $m$ will have an event horizon of radius $2m$ (in units where $\hbar = c = 1$). So the surface area of the black hole is $A = 4 \pi r^2 = 16 \pi m^2$. So any mass $m$ will "gobble up" at least "that much" space. That's the relation to black holes.